# jquery value from checkbox in loop not posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a checkbox with the same name and id but different value.
I trying to get the value when I click on the checkbox in order to pass it to a ajax request. What ever I try I get the same result it only returns the first value in the list (it is actually in a php loop)

```
function checkCheckboxState() {  

    if ($('.displayme').is(':checked')) {

     //tried all of these...

    //var id = $('.displayme').first().attr( "value" ); 
    //var id = $('.displayme').val();
    //var id = $(this).val(); 
      alert(id);

    }

      var id = $(":checkbox[name='displayme']:checked").val();
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="27" id="displayme" class="displayme" onclick="checkCheckboxState()">
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="28" id="displayme" class="displayme" onclick="checkCheckboxState()">
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="29" id="displayme" class="displayme" onclick="checkCheckboxState()">
```

Comment: `I have a checkbox with the same ... id` That's an issue itself. `id` attributes need to be unique. Also, the logic would make more sense if you build an array of the selected checkbox values when you submit the form

Comment: multiple use of the same id is not recommended

Comment: same ID is bad IDea ^^ -> this might be useful to play around with : var id = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){ return $(this).attr("id"); }).get();

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the same id used several times on the same page.

You can bind an event on the change of the checkbox and then get the value with this :

```
$("checkbox.displayme").on("change",function(){
    var checker = $(this).is(':checked');
    //your ajax code here
});
```

And if your checkbox are generated on a php loop, you can use the index of the loop to generate different id (but with the code above you don't need any id).

Comment: `$(this).val($(this).is(':checked'))`?

Comment: Thanks! It was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you have multiple elements with the same `id`. They need to be unique. In this case you could even remove them as you have the common class names to identify the elements.

To solve your actual problem you need to get a reference to the clicked checkbox within the event handler. As you're already using jQuery, you could do that using the `change` event handler. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.displayme').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="27" class="displayme">
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="28" class="displayme">
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="29" class="displayme">
```

Alternatively you can use `map()` to build an array of all the selected checkboxes which can then be passed in a single AJAX request:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.displayme').change(function() {
    var values = $('.displayme:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get()
    console.log(values);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="27" class="displayme">
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="28" class="displayme">
<input type="checkbox" name="displayme" value="29" class="displayme">
```